# Installing GNU make on OpenWrt

Tags: make, openwrt

I'm trying to install [EasyCwmp](http://www.easycwmp.org) on an [OpenWrt](http://www.openwrt.org) installation running as a virtual box, `make` is used in [the installation process](http://www.easycwmp.org/install.html).

but when I type `make` in the shell, it says `/bin/ash: make: not found`

so I [downloaded gnu make](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/) and extracted it, but in its installation guide inside its `INSTALL` file it says:

> 2. Type 'make' to compile the package.

and obviously currently there is no `make` to compile the package.

I also doesn't get the `/path/to/openwrt/package/` in [EasyCwmp installation](http://www.easycwmp.org/install.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openwrt was never meant to have build-essentials like package, you will probably have to build EasyCwmp using the [SDK](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/obtain.firmware.sdk)

This is no easy task, but if you are interested you can use the tutorial to create your own package [here](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/packages)

Answer (score 0):

In the top level there is a shell script `build.sh`. The comments at the start read

```
#!/bin/sh
# Shell script to build GNU Make in the absence of any 'make' program.
```